# date entries in emberjs templates

Tags: ember.js

When I set {{input value=sDate type='date'}} in a handlebar template in emberjs, I get the html5 datepicker when using Chrome.  Unfortunately, html5 datepicker is not supported in Firefox.  How do I switch over to the jqueryUI datepicker instead?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create your own component and to call `element.datepicker();` in your component's `didInsertElement` hook.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `[Ember.Component][1]` implementation of [Bootstrap DatePicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/):

Note: You should be able to adapt the `setupDatePicker` function easily to use jqueryUI datepicker.

#### date_picker_component.js

```
Chipmunk.DatePickerComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  setupDatePicker: {
    var self = this;
    return this.$('.datepicker').datepicker({
      separator: "-",
      autoclose: true
    }).on("changeDate", function(event) {
      return self.set("value", self.format(event.date));
    });
  }.on('didInsertElement'),

  formattedValue: {
    var value = this.get('value');
    if (value) {
      return this.format(value);
    }
  }.property('value'),

  format: function(value) {
    return moment.utc(value).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  }
});
```

#### date-picker.handlebars

```
<div class="date datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
  <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" readonly {{bindAttr value="formattedValue" rel="rel"}}>
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

### Usage:

```
{{date-picker value=sDate}}
```